# Integerate JSP into Joomla as iframe

Tags: linux, jsp, joomla, file-permissions, integrate

I have a Joomla (nginx + mysql) site running as UI and some JSP (tomcat + mysql) handling calculation logic.

I want to integrate JSP pages in to Joomla as iframe. I succeeded doing that, but the question is:

How do I make JSP pages NOT visitable to public but only visitable via Joomla site?

For example,

Joomla site is under mydomain.com/Joomla

JSP pages are under mydomain.com/JSP

When a user visit mydomain.com/JSP in the browser, the user cannot see the JSP page(see error or empty page instead).

But when the user open mydomain.com/Joomla in the browser and go to the page that contains the JSP site within an iframe, the user can see the JSP page there.

I am thinking about changing folder/file owner and permission. Am I on the right track? How should I approach exactly?

Thanks,

Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the way you're currently workin on.

1) Use composent **JUMI** to create virtual Joomla component based on your scripts.
2) On each page add this code at the very beginning of each of your scripts:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die ('Restricted Access');
?>
```

It'll prevent users for loading directly your scripts without any active Joomla session.